# BootStrap Accordion Panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to build Accordion Panel using Bootstrap. But when i am clicking on the link, it doesnt collapse. I am not sure what is the problem. The Bootstrap.css, i downloaded it from the official bootstrap website.  here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2>Accordion</h2>
          <hr/>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#section1">
                    Question1
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <!--  End of heading -->
              <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="section1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  This is the body
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The code is good . you might have wrong boostrap css ref . Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/f8ypa/1193/

Comment: Check your console for errors as you may not have `jQuery` and `BootstrapJS` loaded.

Comment: include bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is good but you are missing Jquery and Bootstrap js

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2>Accordion</h2>
          <hr/>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#section1">
                    Question1
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <!--  End of heading -->
              <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="section1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  This is the body
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

see the updated jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/pup3xtto/